# How to read Telegram channel with Golang?

Tags: python, go, telegram, telethon, pyrogram

I would like to compare the speed of getting Telegram channel updates (new messages) using Python vs Go. In Python I choose [pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/), because in my experience it is a bit faster than [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon).
Actually I want to get new messages as fast as possible, so the idea is to try Go. I'm aware of various Go Telegram libraries (i.e. [telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api)), but it seems they are good for creating bots and not for mimicking user (such as reading messages in channels).

So the question is: what Go library is capable of reading Tg channels?

I will consider other languages as well if they could promise benefit in terms of speed.

Comment: The speed of such operations will most probably be dominated by network I/O, hence unless you're about to create some service which will somehow handle reading of at least hundreds of thousands TG channels concurrently, the selection of the programming language is irrelevant—even the slow-as-molasses Python can do fast network I/O these days using `asyncio`.

Comment: …and while we're at it, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to understand why your question will be closed. You should have done that before posting but oh well. You can see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community) to learn about venues which can be used to ask Go-related questions like yours (which are explicitly unfit for SO).